# Datagrip IDE Fails to connect to MySQL with CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I'm trying to connect to a local MySQL database on my machine with the Datagrip IDE from jetbrains.

When I connect I get this error:

```
[08001] CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required.
```

I can log in locally on the command line without a problem:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password: ***************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 17
Server version: 5.1.73-community-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I can also connect to my postgres database DB just fine using Datagrip. It's only when I connect to MySQL that I get the error.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You should choose the right version of the driver to connect to mysql.
For instance, if you have MySQL server at version 5.x with x <=1, you'd use mysql driver version 5.1.
You have 5.1.73!
Simply, in DataGrip, open the properties of the database connection and click on "driver" link. Then choose mysql driver v5.1. Let it download and install and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had to select the `MariaDB` connection type in Datagrip. Then I could connect to my database. I must have installed MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Comment: Could you execute `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` just to understand what you've installed?